# how to read trace

Tags: c#

I have a snipnet which writes user name to trace.

```
Trace.WriteLine("Current User: " + userIdentity.Name);
```

How to read this information. I did good search in  net, no luck. Can we read default trace?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Take a shot at Log4Net as a tracing tool it's really powerful and simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**the default trace listener writes into Console.**
you can see its output in the debugger using CTRL+W ,O
(View->Output)

you need a proper Trace listener
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx

when you use `Trace.WriteLine()`
all the trace listeners catch this and write

my personal favorite is [XmlWriterTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener.aspx)

just do like this

`Trace.Listener.Add(new XmlTraceListener (tracefilepath));`

use `Trace.WriteLine()` and watch how it creates a nice xml file
that can be easily viewed using [Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

Comment: @Litvin Many thanks for your answer. Cant we read trace info without creating a xml file.

Comment: @Nani where DO you want to read it?
you can create your own using this tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2680/Writing-custom-NET-trace-listeners

or just use the defualt. it writes to the console as i wrote above.