# Include full trace with stack trace / error output c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using the following code in my `global.asax` file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    string err = "Error Caught in Application_Error event<hr />" + "Current User: " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "<hr />" +
            "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
            "<hr />Error Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
            "<hr />Stack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
    //EventLog.WriteEntry("Sample_WebApp", err, EventLogEntryType.Error);

    doEmail.sendEmail("Application Error - Curato (" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganisationName"].ToString() + ")", err);

    // We do not want the error handled by the web.config as well, so clear the error.
    Server.ClearError();
    // Now redirect ourselves...
    Response.Redirect("~/error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
}
```

This sends the stackTrace and current user to an admin email address, and redirects the user to a friendly error page.

**How would I be able to include the full Trace information in `err`? That is, the same information as if I had set `Trace="True"` in the `<%@ Page` directive.**

I'm exploring the `Trace` object - and found how to read it from a 3rd party reader [how to read trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929751/how-to-read-trace) but I'd like to read it just in native code.

Answer (score 0):

You're already getting the full StackTrace of the exception, I believe you're looking at the wrong Exception object:

I think your error is in this line:

```
Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
```

I think the correct one should be:

```
Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError();
```

You can also inspect the exception to see if there are InnerException:

```
if (objErr.InnerException != null)
    err = err + "<hr/>Message:" +  objErr.InnerException.Message;
```

See this question also: 
[Application_Error - GetLastError() or GetLastError().GetBaseException()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085465/application-error-getlasterror-or-getlasterror-getbaseexception)

Comment: Thank you for the answer - the Devil's in the details, I'm specifically after the trace as thought you have enabled trace="true" on the page, so event timings, output from `Trace.Write` and `Trace.Warn`.